# Custom menu item in IBM Connections mobile app

Tags: ios, mobile, ibm-connections

In the mobile app on IOS we would like to have an custom menu item that links to a specific wikipage.
In mobile-config.xml we have added

```
   <Application enabled="true" name="testwiki"> 
               <ApplicationIcon>
                    <Android>
                          <Hdpi>/icec/hdpi/home_icec.png</Hdpi>
                          <Mdpi>/icec/mdpi/home_icec.png</Mdpi>
                          <Ldpi>/icec/xdpi/home_icec.png</Ldpi>
                    </Android>
                    <IOS>
                          <Reg>/icec/IOS/home_icec_normal.png</Reg>
                          <Retina>/icec/IOS/home_icec_normal@2x.png</Retina>
                    </IOS>
                    <BB>
                        <HighDensity>/icec/hdpi/home_icec.png</HighDensity> 
                        <MedDensity>/icec/mdpi/home_icec.png</MedDensity>
                        <LowDensity>/icec/ldpi/home_icec.png</LowDensity>
                    </BB> 
                  <DefaultLocation>/icec/hdpi/home_icec.png</DefaultLocation>
             </ApplicationIcon>
             <ApplicationLabel>Testwiki</ApplicationLabel>
            <ApplicationURL>ibmscp://com.ibm.connections/wikis?action=ShowWikiPage&wiki=d62163a7-3ee4-4b34-a824-7e6d8d2ddc62&page=startpage</ApplicationURL>
    </Application>
```

Then we commit, synk the nodes etc and restart the mobile app. 
After that the mobile app shows "Could not connect"(I think because it is in my native language). 
If we instead set

```
<ApplicationURL>https://connections.connectionsurl.com/wikis/home?lang=sv-se#!/wiki/testwiki/page/startpage</ApplicationURL>
```

it works on the android application but not on the IOS. When using this method we got the following in the loggs:

```
[8/16/18 16:18:47:312 CEST] 000001fc Context       E com.ibm.ws.security.spnego.Context begin CWSPN0011E: A non-valid SPNEGO token has been encountered while authenticating a HttpServletRequest: 0000:  a1143012 a0030a01 01a10b06 092a8648    ..0. .... .... .*.H
0010:  82f71201 0202
```

So should we use ibmscp protocol or it is just for deeplinking into the connections app, the documentation is slightly confusing regarding this?
Or should we use the second method and try to find out why it does not work in the ios? 
Help would be really really appreciated since we are a bit lost at the moment...